# What object, instead of window, has (global) function foo as a property if foo is defined in a javascript file and included from html?

Tags: javascript, html, reflection

If I place the following code in an html file:

```
<script>
  function foo()
  {
  }

  alert("foo" in window);
</script>
```

`true` is shown in a dialog. (see https://jsfiddle.net/f1t2c3kL/ for example.)  But if I move `foo`'s definition to `file.js` and place

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```

in the html header, `false` is shown instead.

What should I use instead of `window` so that the alert shows `true` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order matters: first load, than call.
(And place your scripts before the **closing** `</body>` tag)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>

<script>
    alert("foo" in window); // true
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: That is the order in which I observe `false`.

Comment: Never mind, the issue was my script wasn't within body.